# Why is the CSRF Token value empty/blank in a form when a new session is created?

Tags: forms, session, laravel-4, csrf

I am using Laravel 4 ("laravel/framework": "4.0.*").

I have my login form that uses the Form::open() helper method. The input tag for "_token" gets automatically added to the form as expected, except when a **new session** is created (let's say I clear my cookies), the "value" attribute is missing and there is no token value in the rendered output (View Source).

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden">
```

Only on refreshing the page, the _token value is displayed...

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="FWFOGHSz6oUgYHFblHZ1HrPOZHQC1koF8S52sOL9">
```

If I however manually enter the following in the .blade file...

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
```

... I get the following in the rendered output..

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden">         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="FWFOGHSz6oUgYHFblHZ1HrPOZHQC1koF8S52sOL9">
```

Any clues on why is the Form::open() method auto-magic stuff not working as expected?

**EDIT**
My Form::open() code in the .blade file is as follows:

```
{{
            Form::open(array(
                'url' => URL::full(),
                'class' => 'form-vertical login-form'
            ))
}}
```

Comment: Do you still get the issue after updating Laravel (run `composer update`). If not, please [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that it doesn't stay "unanswered" anymore and serves as a reference for others.